# Recursive loop in a stateless component fails after it starts to walk back up the tree

Tags: reactjs, recursion, jsx

I'm working on a simple recursive loop inside of a stateless component.

I'm trying to print a json object to the screen.

Here is my loop

```
const displayStyles = (themes,elem = '') => {
    let theme = (!elem) ? themes : themes[elem];
    let keys = Object.keys(theme);

    let printStyles = keys.map( (style,i) => { 
        if(typeof theme[style] === 'object' ){
            if(Object.keys(theme[style]).length > 0 ){
                displayStyles(theme[style]);
            }    
        } else {

            return( <p keys={i}>{style}: {theme[style]} </p> )
        }

    })


    return (
        <Code>
            <h4>Styles: {elem}</h4> 
            {printStyles}
        </Code>    
    )

}
```

If works when it hits the bottom of the tree but after that I get nothing printed to the screen.

Any idea where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: You're not returning `displayStyles(theme[style]);` so its result won't be added to `printStyles`.

Comment: Hmm, how can I return something if it's recursive?

Comment: You return the result of `displayStyles`

Comment: Got it. thank you. It's working now.

Comment: There's no such thing as a *"JSON object"* – JSON is always a string

Answer (score 0):

You need to return from the map if `theme[style]` is an object. i.e. when you are calling the function recursively again

```
const displayStyles = (themes,elem = '') => {
    let theme = (!elem) ? themes : themes[elem];
    let keys = Object.keys(theme);

    let printStyles = keys.map( (style,i) => { 
        if(typeof theme[style] === 'object' ){
            if(Object.keys(theme[style]).length > 0 ){
                return displayStyles(theme[style]);
            }    
        } else {

            return( <p keys={i}>{style}: {theme[style]} </p> )
        }

    })


    return (
        <Code>
            <h4>Styles: {elem}</h4> 
            {printStyles}
        </Code>    
    )

}
```